# Ubuntu-Studio Plug-ins GUI broken in Ardour

Tags: gui, plugins, interface, ubuntu-studio, ardour

I use Ubuntu-Studio 12.10 and here's my problem :

When I insert a plug-in on a track , I got a broken interface . I can use most of them without their respective interfaces , but most complex like EQ10Q are pain to use without its interface . The GUI is broken with all plug-in use in Ardour and packed with Ubuntu-Studio 12.10 . The real problem is that with former version of Ubuntu-Studio , plug-ins interfaces were working fine . I've tried Ubuntu-Studio 12.10 on different computers , and the same ! . But the most strange thing is that plug-ins GUI works with other plugin-host softwares like LV2-Rack . Here's screen-shots of the same plug-in but run in different hosts :

LV2-Rack :

http://imageshack.us/a/img547/7214/plughost.png

Ardour :

http://imageshack.us/a/img850/4365/ardourhost.png

I don't know if it's a problem of dependencies or settings , but I hope that someone in the Ubuntu community knows the solution !

Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem and found this: http://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1069173.html

It seems that you have to recompile Ardour yourself. It won't be hard thanks to the apt-build tool. Just issue the following commands (as root):

```
apt-get install libsuil-dev apt-build
apt-build install ardour
```

After executing first command you will be asked about apt-build settings. You can leave defaults or change architecture (setting right architecture for your CPU will make Ardour run faster, but not significantly).

That's all, restart Ardour and enjoy working LV2 GUIs!

Comment: Good ! It works , thanks man ! But , the only problem by recompiling ardour is that it needs Jackd1 , by using Ubuntu-Studio it means that we need to remove lots of packages depending on jackd2 . Fortunately , when Ardour is compiled you just need to re-install some packages previously installed as default like ubuntustudio-audio , ubuntustudio-audio-plugins and some other . It will remove jackd1 but leave the ability for Ardour to correctly display plug-ins GUI ! Thanks a lot !